# N different pin colors for each array of annotations.How?

Tags: ios, iphone, mkannotation

In my app i have n arrays of annotations in my app, foodannotations, gasannotations, and shoppingannotations. I want each array of annotations to show a different colored pin. I am currently using.

Comment: :You got the answer. Post your answer and flag as duplicate. Instead of link show the answer that was more helpful to others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already a discussion was been done regarding this. Please search question if it is already available before you ask. Thanks.

Pls refer the following links:

[iPhone SDK: MapKit multiple custom annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800660/iphone-sdk-mapkit-multiple-custom-annotations)

[Multiple Arrays of Annotations, Different Pin Color for Each Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7084089/multiple-arrays-of-annotations-different-pin-color-for-each-array)

Do this in viewForAnnotation:

```
int annType = ((YourAnnotationClass *)annotation).annotationType;
switch (annType)
{
    case 0 :   //Food
        pinview.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;
    case 1 :   //Gas
        pinview.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;
    default :  //default or Shopping
        pinview.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorPurple;
}
```

Comment: Sorry i dint know. Thanks between.

Comment: Thats okay.I done like this you may get negative marks, Or they may duplicate your question. So please search every time before yu ask if it is already been discussed.

Comment: Yep. The link helped me a lot. Thank you.

Comment: @SiddarthHailstorm link only answeres are discouraged on stackoverflow, please provide the actual answer answers or flag the Question as duplicate.

Comment: @CloudyMarble Sorry sir, sure will edit it with my answer.Thanks

Comment: @siddarth : come on ! Thanks the problem is already solved . I refered the link and made my code. Anyway thanks. Best Wishes.

Comment: @user2918674 : May be it solved your problem just added the code for future reference of programmers facing this issue :)